# Retrieve path instead of data to cached response from URLCache

Tags: swift, urlcache

I want to retrieve the data from a cached `URLResponse` as a local URL or path instead of the `Data` object in memory.

Is this possible? I know that `URLCache` puts its data inside a `Cache.db` file somewhere...

Background: I want to use `URLCache` as my app's cache solution and be able to quickly open `QLPreviewController` to show files. A workaround would be to copy the data to a temp file but I want to know if there's a direct way.

Comment: You can use a [downloadTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411608-downloadtask)? That will download to a file and give you the URL to the corresponding local file.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I updated my question with background info. Basically I want to know if there's a direct way to obtain the path or local url.